# Android- Set Imageview to image from server

Tags: android, xml, url, bitmap, uiimageview

I am trying to set an Imageview to a picture from the internet

this is my xml code

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bg" />
```

and this is my java code

```
ImageView test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getpic);
    test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivget);

    try{
        String url1 =  "http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2012/11/glitter_galaxy/12136712-1-eng-GB/Glitter_Galaxy.jpg";
        URL ulrn = new URL(url1);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        if (null != bmp)
            test.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
    }

}
```

When I run the application the imageview just stays the same as the picture it is set to. If delete the imageview src the screen is just blank.

the android manifest has the Internet permission.

Anyone know why it isnt working?

Comment: You should always print the exception you're catching, otherwise you wouldn't know what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use background thread to download anything from internet and update the UI views.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AsyncTask for downloading image from server like:

```
public class loadSingleView extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleImageViewActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Connect to Server");
            pDialog.setMessage("This process can take a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on your Internet Connection Speed.");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            try {  
                Intent in = getIntent();

                big_image_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_BIG_URL);
                title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
                artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);


                url = new URL(big_image_url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
                conn.setDoInput(true);   
                conn.connect();     
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {       
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return null;   
        }
            @Override       
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
         TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_title);
            TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_artist);



            lblName.setText(title);
            lblCost.setText(artist);

            ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
            ab.setTitle(title);
            ab.setSubtitle(artist);

            view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);
            view.setImageBitmap(bmImg);


        pDialog.dismiss();


    }
```